# What is the exact range of the Extra Utilities Magnum Torch?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

All the various wikis give the range of the Magnum Torch from Extra Utilities as "a radius of 32 blocks".

What shape is that? Circular, Rhomboid, or Square?

In particular, if I make a grid of them, how far apart can they be?

I'm playing Agrarian Skies version v3.1.4 (MC v1.6.4) if versions matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elliptical. From the [FTB wiki](http://ftbwiki.org/Magnum_Torch):

> The Magnum Torch is a torch added by the Extra Utilities mod, which outputs the same amount of light as a vanilla Torch, but in addition it also prevents mobs from spawning in a sphere-like area with a horizontal radius of 128 and a vertical radius of 32 blocks. It will however not disable monster spawners within its radius. Magnum Torches will not stop the spawning of non-hostile mobs. Example: Light Mages from Ars Magica 2 or breeding of animals.